# C# Hook Windows Processes to Check for Debugging Processes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, hook

I was wondering if there is a way I could hook the windows processes to check if any suspicious programs are running like (Wireshark, Fiddler, OllyDBG, etc).

I want to hook the windows processes so it will close the client or pop-up a message in real time when it detects a unwanted process.

If you guys can provide me with any links to doing this that would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: This won't stop a disassembler or people renaming `ollydbg.exe` to something else. Don't blindly believe that this will prevent anti-tampering (though it may slow someone down for a minute or two). Make sure you have other defences.

Comment: I also check the windows titles of these processes.

Comment: There are anti detection plugins for ollydbg for almost any userspace detection method you can imagine. And why are wireshark, olly,... evil?

Comment: @CodeInChaos People can sniff/debug your program to either server emulate or crack it.

Comment: @xZerox thank you for your question - do you have a solution to assist people in the same position you were in six years ago?

Answer (score 1):

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Then walk the list and do as desired for your apps you do not want to run.

Comment: I want to hook the windows processes, sort of like hooking a keyboard to have a real time "key logger".

Comment: @AaronMcIver hey Aaron thank you for your answer. would you know the names of the processes used by common cracking software?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect process creations by using WMI creation events for [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx). An instance of `Win32_Process` is created with each process, so looking new instances will tell you about process creation in (near) real time.

To receive WMI creation events see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.eventquery.aspx (EDIT: different link, now to sample in C#).

Answer (score 0):

[EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(VS.85).aspx) enumerates all top level windows.

And you don't want to inject a C# dll into other processes. This requires the .net runtime to be loaded into that process. This wastes RAM, and if the process is a .net app using a different version of .net then there are versioning problems. Especially if your dll is injected before the process loads its own version of .net.

And what to you want to achieve by injecting into that process you can't achieve from the outside?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out EasyHook on CodePlex (http://easyhook.codeplex.com). [Here](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=42827) is some discussion where people reportedly have been able to hook into CreateProcess. If  you manage to hook into that API function you know of the created process at creation time.