# Help needed with windows hooks

Tags: windows, security, process, hook, monitor

I am working on building a system that can monitor how users react to security alerts on their systems (software updates, warnings etc.). It also needs to monitor the web traffic and the processes running on the system and I am looking to the community to help me design this system. We intend to provide users with test laptops and monitor their behavior over a period of time to see how they react to security alerts thrown by various applications and the OS(windows in this case).

Following are my questions

- Can I use windows hooks to solve the first problem i.e finding how users reacted to the alerts thrown by various applications. Specifically, can global hooks be used to solve this? 
  (How this information should be collected (XML?) and relayed back to a server(how frequently?) is another problem)

  - Can I do this in C# or it has to be done only in c++ or VB?
  - Do you know any alternate approach to solve the problem? Is there any software that has these capabilities.

I have many more questions but getting these answered would be a good first step. Really hoping for some good insights from the knowledgeable people on this community

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**
 Example scenario is when adobe prompts you to update the flash player or the antivirus prompts you to update definitions or any application displays a notification(security related having keywords like update, warning, install etc.) needing the user to take some action. Windows system updates is another example. I want to know how the user reacted to these alerts/notifications/updates (which are typically a pop-up window). So i was wondering if i placed a global hook that can monitor the content of the windows displayed on screen and notify me(server) when certain words like update, alert, warning etc. appear in the content/title of the windows and what the user did with the message(dismissed it, Oked it etc). Unfortunately, i do not have any more specifications than this. I can use anything I want to achieve this and I am not clear on what my choices are.

**Edit 2:**

After having reviewed my requirements and having read about hooks, I feel like I could achieve this by a combination of hooks and the following textGrab SDK,  http://www.renovation-software.com/en/text-grab-sdk/textgrab-sdk.html. I want some guidance to know if I am on the right track. I am thinking if I can install hooks then it gives me handles to all possible windows on the screen and I can use the textGRAB SDK to look for certain keywords in those windows. Although this may capture some interesting text, I am still not sure how I will know what action the user had taken on the window. Anybody having any experience with either hooks or textGRAB, please let me know if this looks like a reasonable thing to do. If the community has some other Ideas on how I could possibly monitor security related messages thrown by any application in the system, please suggest. I am looking forward to some useful advice for completing a challenging project.

Comment: Any attempt at gathering useful data from these applications will be a hack.  You are basically talking about intercepting every windows message and trying to re-build the actions that they took.  The problem with this is that each application can be written different and you will not find a single way to do what you're looking for.  Even if you did manage to make this work, your applications could change at any given time(updates?) and your code would no longer work as you expected.

Comment: If you happened to have control of the applications that you wanted to monitor, it would be one thing.  If this is merely a learning exercise for a small group of people, might I suggest emulating the types of messages you expect them to respond to?  Example: Write an application that displays errors, alerts, warnings, questions, whatever you'd like - and simply record their actions in your favorite format(xml?).

Comment: @syllogism: I have been trying to find out more about hooks and reviewed my requirements. I will need to monitor any application that runs to see if they throw any alerts, warnings or prompt for updates. I am convinced that monitoring is possible through hooks. I hope to install a hook and the filter function that is called will log when some "interesting event" occurs. However, I am still unclear on which exact hook I will need. WH_CBT seems promising but so does WH_SYSMSGFILTER and WH_CALLWNDPROC. I am not sure which hook or combination of hooks is needed for monitoring events from all apps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define, how you will "see" security alerts in code. "Security alert" is quite a vague term. Will it be some window with some caption and some message to the user or ... ?

Next, about web and processes: Windows hooks won't help you with your task. They are more low-level and not as advanced as you'd need. You can't hook network traffic (you need either [network filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546487%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for pre-Vista or [Microsoft Filtering Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx) for Vista and later). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902404/c-hook-windows-processes-to-check-for-debugging-processes) for some information about checking the process list with C# (there seems to be no easy way to catch process startup either).

Comment: I am hoping that when the content of the window (title included) contains certain keywords(eg: warning, update, risk etc) then some notification is triggered. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sid looks too vague anyway. I.e. if this is just for logging, you can grab any message of this kind (Windows hook will let you track windows being shown) and log it. But then you will need to manually verify if messages are really security alerts or something else (such as SO posts in browser windows ;).

Comment: Is the following tool helpful for this purpose? http://easyhook.codeplex.com/ Can I accomplish what I am trying to do by using this? I just want to know if it will be useful. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @Sid you need to distinguish between Windows hooks (SetWindowsHookEx function and related) and "hooking" as a method in general. Detours and EasyHooks hook function calls by injecting code pieces in place of entry points of WinAPI functions. This works, but in general this is hacking, i.e. there exist side effects in this approach (eg. if two applications hook the same function, deactivation of one of the applications can cause troubles). But in general yes, EasyHook will help you hook process creation. But EasyHook is not a replacement for windows hooking mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

It honestly sounds like you need a more solid direction.  I commend you for trying to provide details, but It appears that you still need more information about your problem(s)..

I will attempt to answer some of your questions, but like I said - it sounds like you need to know more about your problems before we can provide you with optimal answer(s).

-Alerts is too vague a term, you will need to define this better.  Are these 'alerts' applications that YOU have control over or are they third party applications?  Not every application will show an 'Alert' in the same fashion, and even if they did - I think using a System Level Hook would probably be too problematic to implement your solution with.  I'm not saying it's necessarily impossible, but you're talking about possibly implementing a different set of logic(to determine the data for a given application's Alert(s)) for each application that you want to monitor.

-It's impossible for any of us to determine the optimal storage mechanism for your particular needs, that is something that you will either need to provide more details about or decide on your own.

-How often you collect data is also something that you will have to either provide more details for or decide for on your own.

-C/C++ Would probably provide you with the most portable solution, although there is nothing preventing you from using c# to call Win32 API. (Not everyone has the .NET framework installed - believe it or not)

-The problem that you mentioned appears to be a somewhat specialized problem... I don't know of any existing software that will do everything that you want to do.

Another possible issue that you haven't touched on:
You haven't specified your target audience for this 'service', but I want you to know that if I found an application monitoring as many events as what you're talking about doing, I would promptly remove it and write a nasty letter to the company that wrote it.

In summary, Read this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) on hooks to get a better understanding of how they work.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for the detailed reply. I want to address the target audience portion first. This is not a service we are trying to sell. This is a system we need to build so that we can carry out a user study and understand how people react to security alerts. In short, this is needed for research. I will edit my question and post an example to make things more concrete.